# Embed YT Live chat on Wordpress letting users interact with it

Tags: wordpress, iframe, youtube, embed

I have successfully embedded a live streaming with corresponding chat into my Wordpress website.

I wish my website users are able to interact with the chat embedded, but also if a user log in to my website using @gmail address, the chat remains not activated showing "sign in to chat" message.

is there a way to allow site users, logged in with gmail credentials, to interact with the chat directly from my site? I noticed that this only works if you browse through Chrome with an account, but on other browsers it doesn't work.